# How to use UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I got `UITableView` in simple view, which controlled by `UIViewController`

I implement methods like in standard `UITableViewController`:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But it doesnt work. Nothing showes in the table

How can i upload the data to this UITableView?

Comment: This is not enough specific info to help you.  Please post the code inside those methods.

Comment: the real question is - How can i upload the data to this UITableView with UIViewController?

Comment: Well, those methods should be implemented by the UITableView delegate. So, as long as you are setting the delegate property on the UITableView to point to the UIViewController (subclass) you should be good to go. Edit: as Gengis noted, delegate **and** dataSource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Did you set the dataSource property of the `UITableView` to point to your `UIViewController`?
- Declare your controller as adhering to the `<UITableViewDataSource>` protocol, in this way you will receive some warning if you missed to implement some required method.

Are you trying to use an `UIViewController` in place of a `UITableViewController`? Why? (As Damien said, this should be the first question).

Comment: While your answer is correct, one can have multiple UITableView(s) in parent view, thus UITableViewController might not be suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but why not use the actual UITableViewController? You can embed it in a UIViewController and make it smaller if you want (like the iOS "Stocks" app from Apple).

There is a lot going on with tableView, which is why when you create a new UIViewController subclass it asks specifically if you want to subclass UITableViewController or UIViewController. Of course you **can** get it to work, but a good first question is why not use UITableViewController?

Again sorry if that isn't really answering the question directly.

Good luck,

Damien

Comment: I cant use UITableViewController, because i must place some other IBOutlets, like labels, button, etc. I cant do it on UITableViewController

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I thought you could set the frame/bounds to be within the UIViewController, in which case you can add controls in the area that is not covered by the UITableView. I can't see the code, but that's what I figure the Stocks app does.

Comment: @Damien: I like your suggestion of embedding the UITableViewController, because this would also solve problems faced when displaying multiple UITableViews at once: You would have one embedded UITableViewControllers for each UITableView. This is a clean code design. However, I've only found code examples which embed UITableViews into other views, and use the UITableViewController only in the way of a data source and delegate (but not as a view controller, e.g. viewDidLoad: will never be invoked). Is there a better way to embed the UITableViewController into another view, e.g. with IB?